# waveform showing only one time after page change hide wave so how fix and showing all time

Tags: node.js, angular, waveform, wavesurfer.js

```
  this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: this.waveformElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement,
        waveColor: '#E7E7E7',
        progressColor: '#222021',
        cursorColor: '#ffffff',
        height: 55,
        barWidth: 8,
        barGap: 3,
        barRadius: 30,
        autoScroll: true,
        autoCenter: true,
        autoplay: false,
      });

      // Handle interaction and start playback
      this.wavesurfer.once('interaction', () => {
        this.wavesurfer?.play();
      });
```

that is my waveform create code and after create waveform show but user change page after waveform is hide so how i fix that issue and user show all time waveform. can you suggest how i show this type wave and i am use wavesurfer.js packge in angular